# Sum up string coincidences multiplied by hash value

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to sum up the number of coincidences of a (number) word within a string matching its value in a hash, only when it strictly appears without any other character, it is to say without prefix or suffix

```
s = "three twot 1three one three"
method(s) #=> 6
method("one on one") #=> 2
method("five monkeys in three farms") #=> 8
method("") #=> 0
method("fivethreeone") #=> 0
```

I can sum up one specific value but unable to do it with more than one:

```
    s = "three twot 1$three one three"

    def method(string)
        num = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5, six: 6, seven: 7, eight: 8, nine: 9 }

    num.each {|k,v|  sum += string.scan(/\b{num.key(v)}\b/).count*num[num.key(v)]}  

    end

    p secret_code(s)
    p secret_code("one on one")
    p secret_code("five monkeys in three farms")
    p secret_code("")
    p secret_code("fivethreeone")
```

Comment: Why does `method("three twot 1three one three")` equal `6` (and not `7`)? You define a method named `method`, but then execute `secret_code`, which is not defined. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = "three twot 1three one three"
number_map = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5, six: 6, seven: 7, eight: 8, nine: 9 }
str.split.map { |word| number_map[word.to_sym] }.compact.inject(:+)    # 7
```

FYI:

```
str.split     # ["three", "twot", "1three", "one", "three"]
str.split.map { |word| number_map[word.to_sym] }    # [3, nil, nil, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution using Array#reduce:

```
WORDS_AND_DIGITS = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5, six: 6, seven: 7, eight: 8, nine: 9 }

s = "three twot 1$three one three"

def method(string)
  string.split.reduce(0) do |sum, number|
    sum += WORDS_AND_DIGITS[number.to_sym].to_i
    sum
  end
end
```

You could definitely mess around with refactoring to take out `#to_sym` and `#to_i`, but this achieves the functionality you described. If the key does not exist in the hash, the return is `nil`, so it is coerced to an integer `0`.

Comment: No need for the second `sum` line. And maybe `hash.fetch(key, 0)` would be more self-explaining than the `to_i` trick?